# SwiftUI: Pass an ObservableObject's property into another class's initializer

Tags: swift, swiftui, observableobject, swiftui-state

How do I pass a property from an `ObservedObject` in a `View`, to another class's initializer in the same `View`? I get an error with my `ObservedObject`:

```
Cannot use instance member 'project' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available
```

---

The reason I want to do this is I have a class which has properties that depend on a value from the `ObservedObject`.

For example, I have an `ObservedObject` called `project`. I want to use the property, `project.totalWordsWritten`, to change the `session` class's property, `session.totalWordCountWithSession`:

```
struct SessionView: View {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    @ObservedObject var project: Project
// How to pass in project.totalWordsWritten from ObservedObject project to totalWordCount?
    @StateObject var session:Session = Session(startDate: Date(), sessionWordCount: 300, totalWordCount: 4000)
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Form {
                    Section {
                        Text("Count")
                        
                        HStack {
                            Text("Session word count")
                            TextField("", value: $session.sessionWordCount, formatter: NumberFormatter())
                                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                        }
                        HStack {
                            // Changing text field here should change the session count above
                            Text("Total word count")
                            TextField("", value: $session.totalWordCountWithSession, formatter: NumberFormatter())
                                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button("Save") {
                        // Save this session into the project
                        project.addSession(newSession: session)
                        isPresented = false
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SessionView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SessionView(isPresented: .constant(true), project: Project(title: "TestProject", startWordCount: 0))
    }
}
```

---

Below is the rest of the example:

[image: HomeView]
[image: SessionView]

HomeView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct HomeView: View {
    @State private var showingSessionPopover:Bool = false
    
    @StateObject var projectItem:Project = Project(title: "Test Project", startWordCount: 4000)
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(projectItem.title).font(Font.custom("OpenSans-Regular", size: 18))
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                Text("Count today: \(projectItem.wordsWrittenToday)")
                Text("Total: \(projectItem.totalWordsWritten)")
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button(action: {
                        showingSessionPopover = true
                        }, label: {
                            Image(systemName: "calendar").imageScale(.large)
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
            
        }.popover(isPresented: $showingSessionPopover) {
            SessionView(isPresented: $showingSessionPopover, project: projectItem)
        }
        
    }
}
```

Session.swift:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class Session: Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    
    init(startDate:Date, sessionWordCount:Int, totalWordCount: Int) {
        self.startDate = startDate
        self.endDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 30, to: startDate) ?? Date()
        self.sessionWordCount = sessionWordCount
        self.totalWordCount = totalWordCount
        self.totalWordCountWithSession = self.totalWordCount + sessionWordCount
    }
    
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    @Published var startDate:Date
    @Published var endDate:Date
    var totalWordCount: Int
    var sessionWordCount:Int
    @Published var totalWordCountWithSession:Int {
        didSet {
            sessionWordCount = totalWordCountWithSession - totalWordCount
        }
    }
    
}
```

Project.swift

```
import SwiftUI

class Project: Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    @Published var title:String
    
    var sessions:[Session] = []
    
    @Published var wordsWrittenToday:Int = 0
    @Published var totalWordsWritten:Int = 0
    
    @Published var startWordCount:Int

    init(title:String,startWordCount:Int) {
        self.title = title
        self.startWordCount = startWordCount
        self.calculateDailyAndTotalWritten()
    }
    
    // Create a new session
    func addSession(newSession:Session) {
        sessions.append(newSession)
        calculateDailyAndTotalWritten()
    }
    
    // Re-calculate how many 
    // today and in total for the project
    func calculateDailyAndTotalWritten() {
        wordsWrittenToday = 0
        totalWordsWritten = startWordCount
        
        for session in sessions {
            if (Calendar.current.isDateInToday(session.startDate)) {
                wordsWrittenToday += session.sessionWordCount
            }
            
            totalWordsWritten += session.sessionWordCount
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `StateObject` initializer in `init`:

```
struct SessionView: View {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    @ObservedObject var project: Project
    @StateObject var session:Session = Session(startDate: Date(), sessionWordCount: 300, totalWordCount: 4000)
    
    init(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, project: Project, session: Session) {
        _isPresented = isPresented
        _session = StateObject(wrappedValue: Session(startDate: Date(), sessionWordCount: 300, totalWordCount: project.totalWordsWritten))
        self.project = project
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world")
    }
}
```

Note that the documentation says:

> You don’t call this initializer directly

But, it has been confirmed by SwiftUI engineers in WWDC labs that this is a legitimate technique. What runs in `wrappedValue` is an `autoclosure` and only runs on the first init of StateObject, so you don't have to be concerned that *every time* your `View` updates that it will run.

In general, though, it's a good idea to try to avoid doing things in the `View`'s `init`. You could consider instead, for example, using something like `task` or `onAppear` to set the value and just put a placeholder value in at first.